# Node exec doesn't have permission to execute script

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, raspberry-pi3

Up until recently, it has worked fine, but when I tried to use it today, it did not work properly. It returns the following error:

> Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c
>   /home/pi/RPi-Computer-Power/RPi-Server/routes/../scripts/hash.js
>   12345678 /bin/sh: 1:
>   /home/pi/RPi-Computer-Power/RPi-Server/routes/../scripts/hash.js:
>   Permission denied

I am extremely confused because when I try to run the script from the command line, it works perfectly; `/home/pi/RPi-Computer-Power/RPi-Server/routes/../scripts/hash.js 12345` executes flawlessly.

This is the code where I try to execute the script. (index.js)

```
exec(__dirname+"/../scripts/"+req.params.script+" "+req.body.params, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log("err: ",err,"stdout: ",stdout,"stderr: ",stderr);
        if(err){
          res.send("<a href='/'>< Back</a> <b>Program Error:</b> "+err.toString());
          return;
        }
        //res.send("<a href='/'>< Back</a> <b>Program Output:</b> <div style='white-space:pre-line>'"+stdout+stderr+"</div>");
        res.render("programOutput", {output: stdout});
      });
```

If anyone has any help, thank you in advance.
Neil

Comment: How are you running node.js?  What permissions does it have?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things come to mind:

1) Make sure that the script you are trying to execute is executable ex: `chmod +x /folder/script`

2) The default terminal shell on many `Linux` distributions is `bash`. The error you displayed includes using `/bin/sh -c`, which would default in many `Linux` distributions to `dash` (yes, a different default `shell` for the terminal and for running scripts without the terminal). Thus, since it seems to work in `bash`, try to evoke the script with `bash -c /folder/script`.

Comment: Yes, thank you, the `chmod +x *` in the scripts directory method worked for me. I thought I tried to `chmod 755 *`, but I guess that wasn't what I needed to do. Thanks!